# Word or adjective for tiles that are detached from the floor?

Tags: word-request

"The * floor tiles were broken into pieces and put in the corner. The whole floor was demolished."

I am not sure if there's a simple way to express this. "Detached floor tiles" doesn't sound very idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Detached tiles = loose tiles. But that doesn't mean "broken into pieces." The floor tiles were broken up and piled in the corner.

Answer (score 1):

"Loose". In the sense meaning "not held together", as in "loose leaf paper", "loose hair", "loose change". (This is not to be confused with loose in the sense meaning "weakly held", as in "loose teeth" or "screws loose". Both of these senses could apply to floor tiles, but in this context it's clear that the tiles are completely disconnected from the floor.)